# Pubsub send_last_published_item is not having effect in openfire

Tags: ios, xmpp, publish-subscribe, openfire

I do not wish for the server to send the last published item every time a subscriber enters their pubsub feed.

Openfire seems to send the most recent message when a user enters their feed for the first time.

I've already changed the send_last_published_item to "never" in the node configuration.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a boolean property, set it to 0 (false).